# Global Wait Cursor

Tags: silverlight

I know this has been asked many times; I'm trying to implement a "global rectangle", with the wait cursor set thereon.

```
<Rectangle Canvas.ZIndex="999" x:Name="WaitCursor" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="Red" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0" Width="1500" Height="1500" Cursor="Wait"/>
```

I can see the ugly red fill the whole page, and the cursor initially changes to waiting, but it seems fragile.  If I move the mouse around, the cursor just seems to randomly switch back (while the screen is still red, of course.)  Worse, if I leave the mouse alone, the wait cursor stays on even after the red rectangle goes away.

Why is this so shoddy???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't bother with the WaitCursor at all, its a fairly poor indicator when compared with other approaches available in Silveright and WPF.

Instead consider using the `BusyIndicator` from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks as usual, Anthony.  The time you spend on here helping people like me is appreciated :)